# loadonce:true is preventing grid update

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jqgrid

On new page load, the grid is properly loading the data from the database.

Afterward, due to `loadonce: true` the grid is not reloading the data from the database for add/edit/delete.

To see newly added data in a list I have to refresh the page.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>

  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="main-content-inner">
      <div class="breadcrumbs" id="breadcrumbs">
        <script type="text/javascript">
          try {
            ace.settings.check('breadcrumbs', 'fixed')
          } catch (e) {}

        </script>
        <ul class="breadcrumb" id="libreadcrumb"></ul>
        <button id="view-fullscreen" style="float: right;height:40px;display:none;" class="ui-state-default white"
          title="Click to View Full Screen">
<span class="ace-icon fa fullscreen ace-icon fa 2x" style="width:40px;padding:0px;">
</span></button>
        <button id="cancel-fullscreen" style="float: right;height:40px;display:none;" class="ui-state-default white"
          title=" Click to Exit Full Screen">
<span class="ace-icon fa resize-small ace-icon fa 2x" style="width:40px;padding:0px;">
</span></button>
        <span id="nghms_time" style="padding-right:20px; float:right;color:#336CBC;font-weight:bold;">
</span>
      </div>
      <!-- end of breadcrumbs-->
      <div class="page-content">

        <div class="row">
          <div id="contentArea" role="main">
            <s:hidden id="profileid" name="profileid" value="27" theme="simple" />
            <div id="businessprofiletab" style="width:100%" class="tabbable">
              <ul id="ulbusinessprofile" class="nav nav-tabs padding-12 tab-color-blue background-blue">
                <li><a href="businessDetails"><span>Business Details</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="businessContacts"><span>Business Contacts</span></a></li>
                <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="communicationEmails"><span>Communication Emails</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="marketingInfo"><span>Marketing Info</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="shipLocations"><span>Ship Locations</span></a></li>
              </ul>
              <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="communicationemails" class="tab-pane in active">

                  <s:form autocomplete="off" id="frmcommunicationemails" name="frmcommunicationemails"
                    action="saveCommunicationEmails" method="post">

                    <s:hidden id="communicationEmailId" name="communicationEmailId" theme="simple" value="0"
                    />
                    <table class="ui-widget-content fullwidth">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="width15">
                            Communication To <em>*</em>
                          </td>
                          <td class="width18">

                            <s:select id="title" name="currentEmail.communicationToId" theme="simple" headerKey=""
                              headerValue="SELECT" list="%{domainTableService.getCommunicationList()}"
                              listKey="communicationListId" listValue="description"
                            />
                          </td>
                          <td class="width10">
                            Email ID <em>*</em>
                          </td>
                          <td class="width17">
                            <s:textfield id="emails" name="currentEmail.communicationEmail" theme="simple" />
                          </td>
                          <td class="width17">
                            <button type="button" id="btnadd_ce" name="btnadd_ce" title="Add Email" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add Email ID
</button></td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <br>

                    <table id="list1"></table>
                    <div id="pager1"></div>
                    <br>
                    <table id="t_communicationemails"></table>
                    <div id="p_communicationemails" class="ui-state-default ui-jqgrid-pager ui-corner-bottom"
                      dir="ltr">
                    </div>

                    <table class="fullwidth">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td width="85%" align="right">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="editbtn_ce" name="editbtn_ce"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-edit"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit Email</button></td>
                          <td width="15%" align="right">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="delbtn_ce" name="delbtn_ce"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-trash"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Delete Email</button>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <br>

                    <div align="right">
                      <s:a action="marketingInfo" name="btnnext" class="btn btn-primary" theme="simple">
                        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-arrow-right"></i>&nbsp;Next</s:a>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                  </s:form>

                  <script>
                    $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
                    $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
                    $(document).ready(function () {

                      $('#rscommunicationemails').dialog({
                        autoOpen: false,
                        title: 'Attention Required',
                        modal: true,
                        buttons: {
                          "Ok": function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                          }
                        }
                      });

                      //Jquery validations ===============
                      $("#frmcommunicationemails").validate({
                        errorClass: "errors",
                        rules: {
                          'currentEmail.communicationToId': "required",
                          'currentEmail.communicationEmail': {
                            required: true,
                            email: true
                          }
                        },
                        messages: {

                          title: "Please Select Value",
                          communicationEmail: {
                            required: "Please provide a password",
                            email: "Please enter Valid Email"
                          }
                        }
                      });

                      //===============

                      jQuery("#t_communicationemails").jqGrid({
                        url: '/Cegnax/customer/communicationEmailsGrid',
                        datatype: 'json',
                        mtype: 'GET',
                        caption: "Emails List",
                        jsonReader: {
                          root: 'gridModel',
                          page: 'page',
                          total: 'total',
                          records: 'records',
                          repeatitems: false,
                          id: '0'
                        },
                        colNames: ['communicationEmailId',
                          'communication To', 'communication Email'
                        ],
                        colModel: [

                          {
                            name: 'communicationEmailId',
                            index: 'communicationEmailId',
                            editable: true,
                            editoptions: {
                              readonly: true
                            },
                            sorttype: 'int',
                            hidden: true
                          }, {
                            name: 'communicationDescription',
                            index: 'communicationDescription',
                            editable: true
                          }, {
                            name: 'communicationEmail',
                            index: 'communicationEmail',
                            editable: true
                          },
                        ],

                        rowNum: 10,
                        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                        rownumbers: true,
                        pager: '#p_communicationemails',
                        sortname: 'communicationEmailId',
                        height: 250,
                        viewrecords: true,
                        sortorder: "desc",
                        autoWidth: true,
                        altRows: true,
                        loadonce: true,

                        loadComplete: function () {
                          var table = this;
                          setTimeout(function () {

                            //  updateActionIcons(table);
                            updatePagerIcons(table);
                            //enableTooltips(table);
                            $("#t_communicationemails").jqGrid(
                              'setGridWidth', $(".page-content")
                              .width());
                          }, 0);
                        },

                      });

                      $("#t_communicationemails").jqGrid('setGridWidth', $(
                        ".page-content").width());

                      jQuery("#t_communicationemails").jqGrid('navGrid',
                        '#p_communicationemails', {
                          add: false,
                          edit: false,
                          del: false,
                          search: false,
                          view: true,
                          addtext: "Add",
                          addtitle: "Add Communication Emails",
                          edittext: "Edit",
                          edittitle: "Edit Communication Emails",
                          searchtext: "Search",
                          searchtitle: "Search Communication Emails",
                          viewtext: "View",
                          viewtitle: "View Communication Emails",
                          refreshtext: "Refresh",
                          refreshtitle: "Refresh Communication Emails",
                          refreshicon: 'ace-icon fa fa-refresh green',
                          viewicon: 'ace-icon fa fa-search-plus grey'
                        }, //general options
                        {
                          editCaption: "Edit Communication Emails",
                          reloadAfterSubmit: true,
                          width: 500,
                          height: 300,
                          closeAfterEdit: true,

                          afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
                            $("#rscommunicationemails").html(response.responseText);
                            $("#rscommunicationemails").dialog('open');
                            return [true, "saved"];
                          }
                        }, //edit
                        {
                          addCaption: "Add New Communication Emails",
                          width: 500,
                          height: 300,
                          closeAfterAdd: true,
                          afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
                            $("#rscommunicationemails").html(response.responseText);
                            $("#rscommunicationemails").dialog('open');
                            return [true, "saved"];
                          }
                        }, //add
                        {}, //delete
                        {
                          closeOnEscape: true,
                          caption: "Search Communication Emails",
                          multipleSearch: true,
                          width: 500,
                          height: 200,
                          sopt: ['eq', 'bw']
                            //odata : ['equal', 'not equal']
                        }, //search
                        {
                          closeOnEscape: true,
                          caption: "View Communication Emails",
                          width: 450,
                          height: 200
                        } //view
                      );

                      $(window).triggerHandler('resize.jqGrid'); //trigger window resize to make the grid get the correct size

                      //resize to fit page size
                      $(window).on('resize.jqGrid', function () {
                        $("#t_communicationemails").jqGrid(
                          'setGridWidth', $(".page-content").width());
                      })

                      $(document).on('settings.ace.jqGrid', function (ev,
                        event_name, collapsed) {
                        if (event_name === 'sidebar_collapsed' ||
                          event_name === 'main_container_fixed') {
                          //setTimeout is for webkit only to give time for DOM changes and then redraw!!!
                          setTimeout(function () {
                            $("#t_communicationemails").jqGrid(
                              'setGridWidth', $(".page-content").width()
                            );
                          }, 0);
                        }
                      })

                      $("#btnnext_ce").click(function () {
                        $('.nav-tabs li:eq(3) a').tab('show');
                      });

                      // button submit click
                      $("#btnadd_ce").click(function () {
                        //java script function for ajax call to check whether the values in db or not
                        $('#frmcommunicationemails').submit();
                        // clearvalues_ce();
                      });

                      // orm submit
                      var options = {
                        //target:'saveBusinessContacts',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
                        beforeSubmit: showRequest, // pre-submit callback 
                        success: showResponse // post-submit callback 

                      };

                      // bind form using 'ajaxForm' 
                      $('#frmcommunicationemails').ajaxForm(options);

                      // pre-submit callback 
                      function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {

                        if ($("#profileid").val() > 0 && $(
                            "#communicationEmailId").val() > 0) {
                          options.url = options.url +
                            "?oper=edit&profileid=" + $("#profileid").val();

                        } else {
                          options.url = options.url +
                            "?oper=add&profileid=" + $("#profileid").val();

                        }
                        return true;
                      }

                      // post-submit callback 
                      function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr,
                        $form) {

                        jQuery("#t_communicationemails").jqGrid().setGridParam({
                          url: 'communicationEmailsGrid?obj=p_communicationemails&profileid=' +
                            $("#profileid").val(),
                          editurl: 'communicationEmailsGrid?obj=p_communicationemails&profileid=' +
                            $("#profileid").val()
                        }).trigger("reloadGrid");
                        clearvalues_ce();
                      }

                      // edit functionality
                      $("#editbtn_ce").click(function () {

                        var id = $("#t_communicationemails").getGridParam(
                          'selrow');

                        if (id == null || id == undefined) {

                          $("#rscommunicationemails").html(
                            '<img src="assets_ace/images/warning.png" height="14px" width="14px"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Please Select Row to Edit'
                          );
                          $("#rscommunicationemails").dialog('open');
                        } else {
                          var rowData = jQuery('#t_communicationemails')
                            .jqGrid('getRowData', id);
                          loadcommunicationemails(rowData.communicationEmailId);
                          $("#btnadd_ce").html(
                            '<i class="ace-icon fa fa-save"></i>&nbsp;&nbspSave Email'
                          );
                        }

                      });

                      $("#delbtn_ce").click(function () {

                        var id = $("#t_communicationemails").getGridParam(
                          'selrow');
                        if (id == null || id == undefined) {

                          $("#rscommunicationemails").html(
                            '<img src="assets_ace/images/warning.png" height="14px" width="14px"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Please Select Row to Delete'
                          );
                          $("#rscommunicationemails").dialog('open');
                        } else {
                          var rowData = jQuery('#t_communicationemails')
                            .jqGrid('getRowData', id);

                          $.post(
                            '/Cegnax/customer/deleteCommunicationEmail', {
                              "communicationEmailId": rowData.communicationEmailId
                            },
                            function () {
                              $("#rscommunicationemails").html(
                                'Email Deleted Sucessfully');
                              $("#rscommunicationemails").dialog(
                                'open');
                              jQuery("#t_communicationemails").trigger(
                                "reloadGrid");

                            });
                        }
                      });

                      function loadcommunicationemails(communicationEmailId) {
                        $.get('/Cegnax/customer/getCommunicationEmail', {
                          "communicationEmailId": communicationEmailId
                        }, function (data) {

                          $("#communicationEmailId").val(data.communicationEmailId);

                          $("#title").val(data.communicationToId);

                          $("#emails").val(data.communicationEmail);

                        });
                      }

                      function clearvalues_ce() {
                        $("#btnadd_ce").html(
                          '<i class="ace-icon fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;&nbspAdd Email'
                        );
                        $("#communicationEmailId").val(data.communicationEmailId);
                        $("#title").val('-1');
                        $("#emails").val('');
                      }

                    });
                    //end of script

                  </script>

                </div>
              </div>

            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: i'm using loadonce :true for pagination

Comment: What is ```load:once```, it is telling to the grid that get all data once and then paginate it on-page itself. If you wrote the pagination code then it will not work.

Comment: @kishor10d thanks for replying then how to implement reload grid using loadonce:true...

Comment: can you please go through this tutorial. but it ```loadonce:false``` which is really a good practice to get only some records per page with ajax.

Comment: `loadonce: true` loads the data from the server and **changes** `datatype` to `"local"`. As the result, `reloadGrid` reloads the current page from *local* data. You can include setting of `datatype: "json"` in the call of `setGridParam`, which you use before `.trigger("reloadGrid")`. Please include always the information about the version of jqGrid which you use and the fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). Free jqGrid supports `fromServer: true` of reloadGrid.

Comment: thanks for replying